# Where should computationally intensive work should be done? Mapper Method or Reducer Method in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I am processing large text files. **Each record is a line** from the input text files and I am searching for certain keywords in these records.
I want to know which of the following **two methods** will be **more efficient**(time complexity) while working in **Hadoop MapReduce**:

1. Searching in **map** function pf the **Mapper**
2. Searching in the **reduce** function of the **Reducer**

Please Help!

Comment: You don't even need a reducer for this.

Comment: suppose I also want to count the number of times a keyword is found

Answer (score 3):

Both should be fine, however, based on your inputs I will try it in the map function because:

Only if you find the keyword, the data is emitted to the group and reduce phase. If the data matching your key words are less, then the overhead of group and reduction reduces significantly.